# Не сохраняются данные в $_SESSION

Tags: php, html, http, сессия

При обновлении страницы (по нажатию определенной кнопки) сиссия каждый раз обновляется, то есть старое значение, сохраненное в ней, я не могу использовать (для того, чтобы, к примеру, накопить сумму чего-либо), хотя вчера этот же код отлично работал и все накапливал, а сегодня — не работает. И еще вылетает ошибка:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at S:\home\shop.by\www\pages\Items\itemsHandler.php:1) in S:\home\shop.by\www\pages\Items\itemsHandler.php on line 1
>
> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at S:\home\shop.by\www\pages\Items\itemsHandler.php:1) in S:\home\shop.by\www\pages\Items\itemsHandler.php on line 1

Почитал на форумах про похожие проблемы, но у меня на первый взгляд все в порядке (мне так кажется).
Возможно, это из-за того, что я отправляю данные методом *POST* в *form*.

Как же решить эту проблему?

```
<?php session_start();

$db =fopen("../../DB/DBItems.txt", "rt");
if ($db)
    while ( $itemInfo = fscanf($db, "%s%d") ){
            list($name,$price) = $itemInfo;
            $_ITEMS[$name] = $price;
            if ($name == $_POST['Button']){

                if (!isset($_SESSION['total'])) 
                    $_SESSION['total'] = 0;
                else
                    $total =$_SESSION['total'];

                if (!isset($_SESSION['countItems[]'])) 
                    $_SESSION['countItems[]'] = 0;
                else
                    ++$_SESSION['countItems[]'];

                $total +=$price;
                $_SESSION['total'] = $total;

            }

    }
else 
    echo "Ошибка при открытии файла";

fclose($db);?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/header.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/index.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/index_footer.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/tovarExample/content.css">
 <title>Shop.by</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <header>
   <div class="headwrapper">
   <div class="BottomLine">
    <div id="logo"> <h2>BIRUANG</h2></div>
    <ul class="info">
    <li>+375 29 145 89 88</li>
    <li>karas-lost@mail.ru</li>
    <div class="BorderBasketLetter">
     <li>
      <a href="basket/basketHandler.php">
       <img src="../../image/header/basket2.png" width="23" height="23" alt="Basket">
      </a>
      <div class="amountOfItemsInBasket">
       <?php echo $_SESSION['countItems[]'];?>
      </div>
      <span>
       <?php  
        echo "$total $";
       ?>
      </span>
     </li>
     <li><span>CHECKOUTS</span><img src="../../image/header/letter.png" width="23" height="23" alt=""></li>
    </div>
    </ul>
   </div>

   <nav id="menu">
    <ul>
     <li id="beginLi">HOME</li>
     <li>MEN
      <!--<ul class="submenu">
       <li>Список 1</li>
       <li>Список 2</li>
       <li>Список 3</li>
       <li>Список 4</li>
       <li>Список 5</li>
      </ul>-->
     </li>
     <li>WOMEN
      <!--<ul class="submenu">
       <li>Список 1</li>
       <li>Список 2</li>
       <li>Список 3</li>
       <li>Список 4</li>
       <li>Список 5</li>      
      </ul>-->
     </li>
     <li>KIDS
     </li>
     <li>SALE</li>
     <li>ABOUT US</li>
     <li>SUPPORT</li>
     <li>
      <input type="text"></input>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
   </div>
  </header>
  <!-- End Header-->
  <div id="content">
   <figure>
    <img src="../../image/pages/tovarExample/Image.jpg" alt="">
    <figcaption>
     <p>Продолжение культовой книги "Тренировочная зона" Пола «Тренера» Уэйда посвящено продвинутым техникам тренировок с собственным весом для развития предельной силы и мышц. </p>
     <p class="price">
      Цена =  <? echo $_ITEMS['Ball'].' $'?>
     </p>
     <form method="POST" action="itemsHandler.php">
      <input type="submit" name="Ball" value="Купить">
      <input type="hidden" name="Button" value="Ball">
     </form>
    </figcaption>
   </figure>
   <figure>
    <img src="../../image/pages/tovarExample/Image.jpg" alt="">
    <figcaption>
     <p>Продолжение культовой книги "Тренировочная зона" Пола «Тренера» Уэйда посвящено продвинутым техникам тренировок с собственным весом для развития предельной силы и мышц. </p>
     <p class="price">
      Цена =  <? echo $_ITEMS['Basket'].' $';?>
     </p>
     <form method="POST" action="itemsHandler.php">
      <input type="submit" name="Basket" value="Купить">
      <input type="hidden" name="Button" value="Basket">
     </form>
    </figcaption>
   </figure>
   <figure>
    <img src="../../image/pages/tovarExample/Image.jpg" alt="">
    <figcaption>
     <p>Продолжение культовой книги "Тренировочная зона" Пола «Тренера» Уэйда посвящено продвинутым техникам тренировок с собственным весом для развития предельной силы и мышц. </p>
     <p class="price">
      Цена =  <? echo $_ITEMS['Box'].' $';?>
     </p>
     <form method="POST" action="itemsHandler.php">
      <input type="submit" name="Box" value="Купить">
      <input type="hidden" name="Button" value="Box">
     </form>
    </figcaption>
   </figure>
   <figure>
    <img src="../../image/pages/tovarExample/Image.jpg" alt="">
    <figcaption>
     <p>Продолжение культовой книги "Тренировочная зона" Пола «Тренера» Уэйда посвящено продвинутым техникам тренировок с собственным весом для развития предельной силы и мышц. </p>
     <p class="price">
      Цена =  <? echo $_ITEMS['Phone'].' $';?>
     </p>
     <form method="POST" action="itemsHandler.php">
      <input type="submit" name="Phone" value="Купить">
      <input type="hidden" name="Button" value="Phone">
     </form>
    </figcaption>
   </figure>
   <figure>
    <img src="../../image/pages/tovarExample/Image.jpg" alt="">
    <figcaption>
     <p>Продолжение культовой книги "Тренировочная зона" Пола «Тренера» Уэйда посвящено продвинутым техникам тренировок с собственным весом для развития предельной силы и мышц. </p>
     <p class="price">
      Цена =  <? echo $_ITEMS['Notebook'].' $';?>
     </p>
     <form method="POST" action="itemsHandler.php">
      <input type="submit" name="Notebook" value="Купить">
      <input type="hidden" name="Button" value="Notebook">
     </form>
    </figcaption>
   </figure>
   <figure>
    <img src="../../image/pages/tovarExample/Image.jpg" alt="">
    <figcaption>
     <p>Продолжение культовой книги "Тренировочная зона" Пола «Тренера» Уэйда посвящено продвинутым техникам тренировок с собственным весом для развития предельной силы и мышц. </p>
     <p class="price">Цена =</p>
     <input type="button" value="Купить"></figcaption>
   </figure>
  </div>
  <!-- End Content-->
  <!-- Footer-->
  <footer>
   <div id="col1">
    <h2>OUR STORES</h2>
    <p>Pellentesque non cursus mi, eu cursus nunc. Nullam
     et odio tristique, volutpat urna vitae, dignissim orci.</p> 
    <p>Fusce eu nulla urna.
     This template was created by Erik Paнтакты для связи с нами</p>
   </div>
   <div id="col2">
    <h2>BLOG POSTS</h2>
    <strong>Nullam et odio tristique</strong><br>
            Nullam et odio tristique, volutpat urna vitae, dignissim orci.Fusce eu nulla urna.</p>
    <strong>Nullam et odio tristiquedignissim orci.</strong><br> 
         Fusce eu nulla urna.This template was created by Erik Paнтакты для связи с нами</p>
   </div>
   <div id="col3">
    <h2>SUPPORT</h2>
    <ul>
     <li>Terms & Conditions</li>
     <li>FAQ</li>
     <li>Payment</li>
     <li>Refunds</li>
     <li>Track Order</li>
     <li>Services</li>
     <li>Privacy & Security</li>
     <li>Careers</li>
     <li>Press</li>
     <li>Corporate Information</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="col4">
    <ul>
     <li>Sizing</li>
     <li>Ordering</li>
     <li>Shipping</li>
     <li>Return Policy</li>
     <li>Affiliates</li>
     <li>Find a Store</li>
     <li>Site Map</li>
     <li>Sign UP & Save</li>
    </ul>
    
   </div>
   <div id="col5">
    <h2>CONTACT US</h2>
    <input type="text" value="Your Gmail">
    <textarea name="yourtext" id="yourtext" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="SEND">
   </div>
  </footer>
 </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Посмотрите логи ошибок или ответ сервера, включая заголовки, в Инструментах Разработчика вашего браузера – похоже, какое-то предупреждение или сообщение об ошибке php идёт на выход скрипта.

Comment: Чего-то вы нам недопоказываете. Ошибки вам прямо говорят что уже пошел вывод тела http  ответа, а в приведенном коде этого не видно

Comment: @tutankhamun, я показал то, что вижу, я все договорил.

Comment: Хотя возможно я просто не знаю как называются приведенные файлы. В ошибке сказано, что вывод начался в первой строке файла itemsHandler.php

Comment: Может просто `<?php`  стоит не в самом начале

Comment: @tutankhamun, это все один файл, просто я так разделил php и ,собственно, html разметку,  он и есть itemsHandler.php.

Comment: @UraOs, файлы сохраните **без BOM** заголовка.

Comment: @Visman, пробовал, но это не помогает.

Comment: @tutankhamun, все теги есть.

Comment: @Sergiks, при GET получаю phperror_js.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибки с текстом *headers already sent by* появляются если перед попыткой отправить HTTP-заголовок веб-сервер уже начал отправлять тело ответа. По опыту это случается в следующих случаях:

1. Скрипт уже получился длинный и программист забыл, что перед функцией `header()` он уже где-то начал формировать страницу (например `echo '<html><head>';`);
2. PHP-файл в unicode-кодировке и в начале файла стоит маркер последовательности байтов ([BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)) или другой неотображаемый символ (например пробел нулевой ширины);
3. В PHP-файле тег `<?php` стоит не с самого начала, а после пробела, табуляции или не на первой строке;
4. PHP выводит сообщение об ошибке или предупреждение при включенной директиве `display_errors` в тело страницы.

Иногда, когда файлов много, разобраться становится трудно. "Поймать" вывод поможет буферизация вывода. Можно в самый первый файл, в самое начало вставить строку: `ob_start();` и перед строкой, отправляющей HTTP-заголовок (функции `header()`, `session_start()`, `setcookie()`) вставить `file_put_contents('content-debug.log', ob_get_contents())` и посмотреть, что будет записано в файл `content-debug.log` (может быть в виде шестнадцатеричного дампа)

Comment: Попробовал file_put_contents('content-debug.log', ob_get_contents()) - файл пустым оказался.

Comment: Судя по `output started at ... itemsHandler.php:1...`, у вас что-то в начале файла перед `<?php` - это точно. Посмотрите hex-редактором что-ли.

Comment: Оу, Обнаружились такие символы - п»ї , только как их удалить в том же Notepad++

Comment: Все, разобрался, как это сделать, ошибка исчезла - огромное всем спасибо, в особенности @ tutankhamun.

Comment: Это BOM. На SO есть ответ с картинкой http://stackoverflow.com/a/8432691/3349900

Answer (score 2):

Полный ответ на ваш вопрос есть в самом вопросе. Другого ответа здесь быть не может.

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session >cookie - headers already sent by (output started at >S:\home\shop.by\www\pages\Items\itemsHandler.php:1) in >S:\home\shop.by\www\pages\Items\itemsHandler.php on line 1

Интерпретатор PHP сообщает вам, что вывод данных начался до вызова функции [session_start](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php), т.о. сессии не могут обеспечить корректное сохранение указанных данных.

Для работы сессий используются Cookie. Сохранение Куки происходит только в области **Заголовков** ответа вашего сервера. Как только вы начинаете передавать любые данные (теги, пробел, абсолютно любой символ) заголовки вы уже не сможете отправить и именно об этом вам говорит ваша ошибка. Нужно найти эти данные до функции [session_start](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php) и переместить, если они нужны, либо удалить.

На вашем примере невозможно определить эти дополнительные данные. В комментариях к вопросу вам предлагали переопределить кодировку файла Unicode  без BOM ([Notepad++ удобный быстрый редактор, смена кодировок в один клик](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)).

Иногда (очень редко) в конфигурации PHP или htaccess указывается [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) который автоматически включает в любой скрипт какой-то другой файл в самое начало и этот файл может передать данные о которых вы можете забыть или не знать. Проверьте конфигурацию PHP.